# How to put images at the top but still be responsive?

Tags: html, css

I want the four social media images to be at the top, but I want to replace the `bottom: 60px;`on the .social with something else. Because if you go on other smaller screen devices it goes off the screen, other words 60px up (not responsive).

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tw0eh26s/5/) might make it easier to understand.

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: url(https://i.ibb.co/VH659W4/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
.row {
    display: flex;
    z-index: 2;
    justify-content: center;
}
.social {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    bottom: 60px;
}
#header {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>
            DJ JUMO
        </title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="header" src="https://i.ibb.co/gdHS8by/header.png" alt="logo">
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/djjumo/" target="_blank"><img class="social" src="https://i.ibb.co/N7dFXZ4/instagram.png"></a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="" target="_blank"><img class="social" src="https://i.ibb.co/s3VrxZJ/twitter.png"></a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="https://www.snapchat.com/add/djjumo" target="_blank"><img class="social" src="https://i.ibb.co/prCyYw3/snapchat.png"></a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="" target="_blank"><img class="social" src="https://i.ibb.co/5Y77Bcm/facebook.png"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally if you want the images to be on *top* (above) the image, you'd structure your HTML as such, by moving the `.social` elements above your independent `<img>` tag.

From here you can work from the *top* instead of from the `bottom`.

However, note that instead of `top`, you'll want to use `margin-top`. Otherwise you'll have giant click-zones well outside of the child `<img />` tags.

I've swapped to this in my example (note you may need to adjust the `margin-top` value):

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/VH659W4/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  z-index: 2;
  justify-content: center;
}

.social {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#header {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>
    DJ JUMO
  </title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/djjumo/" target="_blank"><img class="social" src="https://i.ibb.co/N7dFXZ4/instagram.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="" target="_blank"><img class="social" src="https://i.ibb.co/s3VrxZJ/twitter.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="https://www.snapchat.com/add/djjumo" target="_blank"><img class="social" src="https://i.ibb.co/prCyYw3/snapchat.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="" target="_blank"><img class="social" src="https://i.ibb.co/5Y77Bcm/facebook.png"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img id="header" src="https://i.ibb.co/gdHS8by/header.png" alt="logo">

</body>

</html>
```